# Why VS2022 Keeps logging me to wrong server

Tags: azure, visual-studio, server, azure-web-app-service

I've doing a project using the azure servers for a little bit now. After a month my subscription ended, and I had to get a new one, with a new acc (school project, so im too poor to get the normal sub). Now after setting everything up, and trying to connect to my new databasa (which to its address has added 2 at the end), my VS still tried to log me into the old server.
I've already tried to delete the whole project, copying it anew from gitlab, deleting cache from my pc, restarting it, and adding/removing connections in VS, but when the error occurs.

I'm getting the "Login failed for user X", when I'm checking the logs of the error, I see that it still tries to connect to the old server.

Any ideas what could cause it to keep logging to the old server?

I'm using in this part of the program only 1 Connection string, which I have changed to the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, apologies for the delayed response. As I understand you have tried multiple things to narrow the issue.

•   Does this issue occur only when deploying to Azure App Service WebApp or happens for local deployments?

If you haven’t tried these already, please try to isolate the issue further.

- You may directly login to your Azure subscription via Azure Portal,
  and find (status) the deployment/resources. https://portal.azure.com/
- Try deleting my local publish profile and then re-add it again with the profile.publishssettings , by downloading from the Azure Portal.
- In the VS Tools Menu >>  Options >> Azure Service Authentication. Under the Choose an account drop down >> open new profile window, and re enter your credentials (and cancel creating new profile).

If the issue still persists, please let us know, I'll follow-up with you further.